# Height of UINavigationBar in UITableView doesn't change

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tabbed application, containing as a first tab **"Home"**, which is the initial view controller. **Home** is a `UITableViewController` and conforms to `BETableViewController`, as all the tabs of the app, and is embeded in a `UINavigationViewController`.

When you select a row in **Home**, you get to `ArticleViewController`, conforming to `BEViewController` .

`BEViewController` and `BETableViewController` have a large (height has been enlarged) `UINavigationBar` containing a logo; those changes come in the `viewDidLoad()` function of each Controller.

The problem is that, when i load the app,  **Home** shows a normal sized `UINavigationBar` with the logo protrudind into the TableView.
. When I select a row, it takes me to `ArticleViewController`, which does show the wanted results in the navigation bar. Wheni go back to **Home**, through the back button, **Home** shows the intended results.

I'll include the screenshots and some code.

```
class BEViewController: UIViewController {

var logo = UIImageView() //CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    logo.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width / 2 - 40, y: 20, width: 80, height: 80)
    logo.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "logo")

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(logo)
    }
}

class BETableViewController: UITableViewController {

var logo = UIImageView() //CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    logo.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width / 2 - 40, y: 20, width: 80, height: 80)
    logo.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "logo")

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(logo)
    }

}
```

[Image 1: Initial **Home**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npC5d.png)

[Image 2: ArticleViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D71tj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set the size of image in Navigation Bar less than 49 pt. Please refer [Apple Guidelines - Navigation Bar](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/navigation-bars/)

Comment: Isn't there a way to make the `UINAvgationBar` like I want it?

Comment: Height of `UINavigationBar` should always be 49 pt, so that it should look nice with respect to Apple's design guidelines. Making changes to those will either get your application to be **rejected**. Only solution I find is to use a `44pt x 44pt` image at center.